# Xamarin forms Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

My application is based on masterdetailedpage navigation and I am working with push notification. When user click on the notification I want to navigate to a specific page. All the process is working fine but at the end of the proccess I got this error Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed .

My code for push notification is based on this link : https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/so-i-just-implemented-push-notifications-in-awesome-xamarin-forms/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to the Notification Hubs code. Google the error message and you'll see that people get it for all sorts of reasons, there doesn't seem to be a specific root cause. You'll need to go through a few of those cases and see how it applies to your code.

Comment: This might be the same issue as [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46494) which is fixed in Forms 2.3.4-pre1.

Comment: @jimmgarr I update forms to 2.3.4-pre1 but error still exists

Comment: @MostafaMarji please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with reproduction steps to help investigate this further. Thanks!